# Geogebra: construct the smallest circle of a polygon

Tags: circles

i want to solve the smallest-circle problem of a convex polygon with arbitrary nodes with geogebra.

I know how to do it for a triangle, but that does not help me with other convex polygons.
I read about some algorithms (e.g. Welzl algorithm), but i don't know how to implement it in geogebra.
Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: What is “the smallest circle of a polygon”? Is it the smallest circle containing all points of the polygon?

Comment: Yes i meant the smallest enclosing circle that contains all points. Like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem#:~:text=The%20smallest%2Dcircle%20problem%20(also,points%20in%20the%20Euclidean%20plane.